# Laravel Tenanti : Default driver not implemented

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to implement Orchestral/Tenanti for creating databases for each company registered to my app.

When I added Database Connection Resolver as mentioned in 
https://github.com/orchestral/tenanti I get the following error

> InvalidArgumentException Database connection [tenants] is not available.

After googling, I found the answer by cynobone on stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33320724/9604136 where setupMultiDatabase is used instead of connection which gave me another error

> InvalidArgumentException Default driver not implemented.

For my app, as I was creating new database for each company, I changed accordingly

tenanti.php

```
'drivers' => [
    'company' => [
        'model'  => App\Company::class,
        'path'   => database_path('tenanti/company'),
        'shared' => false,
    ],
],
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{

    Tenanti::setupMultiDatabase('tenants', function (Company $entity, array $config) {
        $config['database'] = "comp_{$entity->getKey()}"; 
        // refer to config under `database.connections.tenants.*`.

        return $config;
    });    
}
```

database.php

```
'tenants' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'dbhost',     // for user with id=1
        'username'  => 'dbusername', // for user with id=1
        'password'  => 'dbpassword', // for user with id=1
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

I am also in dilemma that where to put

```
$user = App\User::whereSubdomain($request->route()->parameter('tenant'))->first();
Tenanti::driver('user')->asDefaultDatabase($user, 'comp_{id}');
```

I am trying to authenticate users from my main database and when authenticated, use database made for that authenticated user particularly.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, following Tenanti's GitHub readme notes also stumped me, but cynobone's post 
helped with the first problem, however that has also brought me to the second problem:

> InvalidArgumentException Default driver not implemented.

*Note that I'm configuring Laravel 5 project with default settings in the app\config\database.php file

Here's the content of said file:

```
'connections' => [
'superadmins' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SECOND', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SECOND', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => env('DB_MYSQL_STRICT_MODE', true),
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

This is only part of the file and the others are just default stuff.

In my case I changed the connection 'tenants' to new connections named 'admins' and 'superadmins', but it should be the same as your 'tenants' connection. The default connection is the one named 'mysql' which I followed to make the 2 new connections.

I fixed the quoted error by copying

```
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => env('DB_MYSQL_STRICT_MODE', true),
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
```

...into the 'tenants' connection and it fixed the error. Hope that it does the same to you as well.

Also, you need to put

```
$user = App\User::whereSubdomain($request->route()->parameter('tenant'))->first();
Tenanti::driver('user')->asDefaultDatabase($user, 'comp_{id}');
```

...in a middleware which you will need for authenticating different users in your web app.

Cheers.